# Displaying the sum of expenses in my dashboard page

Tags: python, html, django

Hello guys so I have an expense app that helps to keep track of all expenses in a project but I want to display the sum of all these expenses on the dashboard page so that when the user logs in they can see the total expenses of a particular project. I already have a html file (expenses.html) which shows a table of all expenses (but not the sum) so I was thinking maybe there is a way I can calculate the sum and incorporate it in the dashboard page.

So here is how I tried doing it with no success;

1. I created a model in my models.py (of the dashboard)

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
```

2. Then went to my view.py (of the dashboard) to define a function called total_expenses.

```
def total_expenses(request):
    total_expenses = Expense.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))
    return {'total_expenses': total_expenses['total']}
```

3. After that I returned to the dashboard.html and wrote this;

```
    <div class="card mt-3">
        <a class="nav-link"  href="{% url 'expenses' %}">
            <h5 class="card-category">Total Expenses</h5>
            <h2 class="card-title"> ({{ total_expenses }}) </h2>  
        </a>
    </div>
```

I want the sum to be displayed in the brackets as shown in the following image:
[image: Tab to display the sum]

I know it is not a lot but I would appreciate any help and feel free to ask for any information.

My urls.py for the dashboard:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns =[
    path('', views.index, name="dashboard"),
]
```

My views.py for the dashboard:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Expense
from django.db.models import Sum

# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url='/')
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html')

def total_expenses(request):
    total_expenses = Expense.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))
    return {'total_expenses': total_expenses['total']}
```

Comment: Can you add your `urls.py` and `views.py`? I think something is missing.

Comment: Ok I have edited in the main post

Comment: Seems like you have 1 url route but two views. That looks a bit confusing to me. If you want to show the SUM of all expenses, why not do the query for `total_expenses` in the `index` view?